# UK visa for baby born in UK and applying settlement visa from India - Is Tuberculosis certificate mandatory?

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit, indian-citizens, dependent-visa, children

I have ILR and my son was born in UK in May 2020. In Jan 2021 we got him an Indian passport and immediately we travelled to India for emergency reasons in Feb 2021. Now in March 2021 we need to apply for a child settlement visa from India as we need to travel back to UK by May 2021. The quesion: Would he need a TB test done and attached with the UK visa application as we will have been in India, at maximum, 4 months?

The below link it says that if we are not away from UK for more than 2 years, or if we have not stayed atleast 6 months in a country from where a TB is not required, then the TB test is not mandatory.

Could  you please confirm that it is correct that we dont need the TB screening test requrired for my son for his UK application submission.

The TB test gov link states the following:

You will not need a TB test if any of the following apply:

- You’re a diplomat accredited to the UK
- You’re a returning UK resident and have not been away for more than 2 years
- You lived for at least 6 months in a country where TB screening is not required by the UK, and you’ve been away from that country for no more than 6 months
  Does she fall under the second point as she was born in UK and has not been away for more than 2 years?

Comment: Did you have ILR when your son was born?

Comment: No .. unfortunately ILR appointment has got dealyed. Im planning to apply the child settlement visa for my son from India.

Comment: Darn.  I was hoping to be able to answer that your child cannot get a visa because your child is a British citizen.  But as you are apparently aware, the fact that you received ILR after your child's birth means that your child really isn't a British citizen.  I've therefore upvoted the question, but I doubt I'll be able to find an answer for it.